# MySQL: select last (max) value from column and count of all rows

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select last (=max) value from column and count of all rows in single query?

```
ID      ITEM_ID       VALUE
1       1             100
2       1             101
3       2             201
4       3             333
5       2             222
6       1             111
```

I want to select last / max value for particular ITEM_ID and count of all rows with this ID.
For ITEM_ID = 1 thus:

```
VALUE      COUNT
111        3
```

My query is like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) AS count, (SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS value FROM table WHERE item_id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

It works but looks ... weird. Is there any better (simpler / faster) solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `GROUP BY` on column `ITEM_ID` while getting the `MAX()` and `COUNT()` like

```
select max(value) as `VALUE`,
count(*) as `COUNT`
from your_table
group by ITEM_ID;
```

Comment: I'm still puzzled by the last / max term. The former would require a variable I guess.

Comment: @amenadiel, I believe OP means max value per item_id. that's what he is terming as last value.

Comment: Yes, last VALUE for particular ITEM_ID is always its MAX value. Thanks Rahul, this works great.